# Python3 ignores __init__.py on Windows, but not in OS X

Tags: python-3.x, package, python-import

I have a package with a name `parser` (which shadows a built-in module `parser`), and I'm importing it:

```
import parser
```

This works in OS X, but not in Windows. I've checked that `__init__.py` of my `parser` package is executed correctly in OS X. However, it doesn't work in Windows. This is what I get in OS X:

```
>>> import parser, sys
>>> print(parser)
<module 'parser' from '/Users/apple/Development/tiny-py-interpreter/tinypy/parser/__init__.py'>
>>> for path in sys.path: print(path)
...
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python35.zip
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/plat-darwin
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

What I get in Windows:

```
>>> import parser
>>> parser
<module 'parser' (built-in)>
>>  for path in sys.path: print(path)
...
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\python34.zip
C:\Stuff\Python34\DLLs
C:\Stuff\Python34\lib
C:\Stuff\Python34
C:\Stuff\Python34\lib\site-packages
```

Renaming `parser` to another name makes it work in Windows. Both systems have plain stock python3 setup.

Directory structure is the following:

```
main.py 
parser
|--- __init__.py
```

Is it a correct behaviour? Why it doesn't happen in OS X, and does in Windows?

Comment: My first guess would be the case-sensitivity of Windows. Is your module possibly named "Parser", not "parser"?

Comment: @MattW., no, it is named "parser".

Comment: is the parent folder of `parser` in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: @BryanOakley PYTHONPATH is empty, PATH doesn't contain a reference to the parent folder.

Comment: Do `>>> import sys; sys.path` on both systems before the import and check for differences.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy there are only default directories on both systems, and nothing more.

Comment: Please update your question with the results of the two `sys.path` prints.

Comment: Where is your `parser` package located?

Comment: @EthanFurman full path is `'/Users/apple/Development/tiny-py-interpreter/tinypy/parser/` in OS X and `C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tiny-py-interpreter-master\tinypy\parser` in Windows

Answer (score 0):

In order for shadowing to work, the user directories must come before the stdlib directories.  Depending on the O/S and the particular Python environment (conda? stock? enthought? etc.) that may or may not happen.